# Vue Get form data as object when taken in as a slot

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

I am currently creating a wizard tool where the user can create the wizard like so:

```
<wiz>
 <form>
  <page>
   <label />
   <input />
  </page>
  <page>
   <label />
   <input />
  </page>
 </form>
</wiz>
```

Anything inside the wiz tag is taken in as a slot. And inside the wiz component I slot whats inside the `<page>` tags into different tabs in the wizard.

I am currently having difficulties when I want to get the form data of the form the user put inside the wizard, I've been looking online but all the solutions I found basically work by you knowing what the labels/inputs of the form will be and building your JSON object with that knowledge.

As for me I have no idea what the contents inside the wizard will actually be as it depends on the user.
I also hope to have the submit button outside the  tag if at all possible, though if not It is understandable.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like `element.querySelectorAll('input, select, textarea')` or `document.forms['form_name'].getElementsByTagName('input');` to capture all the form elements. You could then iterate though them to find the values and construct a JSON object (or whatever format you need the data in).

Comment: In the end I found a solution through references using your idea by trying to find the elements. Thank you :)